# Trust Firebase rules with UID to keep data secure

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

If a hacker has the UID of a user and the firebase config, will all the rules that secure the user data with uid fail ?

```
 "rules": {
"profiles": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth.uid == $uid,
    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid',
  },
```

Can such rules be deceived easily if the above conditions are true ?

How do I practice better rule structure to make sure my data is as safe and additional security that I can apply to make my data safe for business use.

Answer (score 1):

Those rules:

```
"rules": {
 "profiles": {
   "$uid": {
     ".read": "auth.uid == $uid,
     ".write": "auth.uid == $uid',
   },
```

Those rules mean if the user is authenticated then he is able to read and write data to the database.

The `uid` is provided by firebase authentication. Even the end user does not know his `uid`, you are the only person that knows it and the collaborators in the project if they have that specific role.